# Drawing bounding box with ImageAI

Tags: python, object-detection, bounding-box, resnet, imageai

I am using ImageAI to draw bounding boxes on images.

```
from imageai.Detection import ObjectDetection
detector = ObjectDetection()
detector.setModelTypeAsRetinaNet()

# Load model
model_path = 'resnet50_coco_best_v2.0.1.h5'
detector.setModelPath(model_path)
detector.loadModel()
```

This raises an error:

```
----> 6 detector.setModelPath(model_path)
ValueError: invalid path, path not pointing to a valid file.
```

However, 'resnet50_coco_best_v2.0.1.h5' file exists (https://github.com/OlafenwaMoses/ImageAI/releases/tag/1.0).

Could you suggest I can fix this error? Thank you.

Comment: Were you able to solve this? I'm able to run the code, but unable to draw the bounding boxes.

Comment: No sorry, the code doesn't work for me

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to download it and set the path to the file in `model_path` . For example if you have the file in the same folder as the script the path would be `'./resnet50_coco_best_v2.0.1.h5'`

Comment: Do you mean "download the file and set `model_path` to the file's path?"